# Table View Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

Currently I have an array of objects right now

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.webSites = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Website", @"iOS", @"Android", nil];

}
```

I am trying to access the one at index:0 which should be Website with the following code to perform a segue to another table view controller where there will be categories to select from.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"viewCategories" sender:nil];
    }
}
```

Every time I run the app I click on Website and nothing happens, but when I click on iOS the segue performs. Any answer as to why I'm running into this problem?

Comment: Why are you using deselect rather than select?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using wrong method.

```
didDeselectRowAtIndexPath // Used for deselecting the cell row
```

should be

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath  // Used for selecting the cell row
```